# DuckDB - efficiently insert pandas dataframe to table with sequence

Tags: python, sql, pandas, duckdb

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp (
    id UINTEGER,
    name VARCHAR,
    age UINTEGER
);
CREATE SEQUENCE serial START 1;
```

Insertion with series works just fine:

```sql
INSERT INTO temp VALUES(nextval('serial'), 'John', 13)
```

How I can use the sequence with pandas dataframe?

```py
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
print(df)
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13

con.execute("INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM df")
RuntimeError: Binder Error: table temp has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied
```

I don't want to iterate item by item. The goal is to efficiently insert 1000s of items from python to DB. I'm ok to change pandas to something else.

Comment: have you tried using pandas `to_sql` function?

Comment: @oskros DataFrame.to_sql()? How can make a dataframe with SEQUENCE in it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you have nextval('serial') as part of your select query when reading the df?

e.g.,

```
con.execute("INSERT INTO temp SELECT nextval('serial'), Name, Age FROM df")
```